# Constant of Integration Confusion

Tags: integration

I know that

[image]

however, in order to satisfy somewhat of a mathematical curiosity I attempted to solve this integral in a sort of unorthodox manner. My process is shown below.

[image]

Although the second method may seem longer, I expected to get the same answer at the end, however I always get a + 1 after the ln term. I do not know whether this is just a constant of integration or whether I am doing something incorrect.

Comment: It's a constant of integration.

Comment: All 'extra' constants get absorbed into a final constant. This happens a lot. For example, try integrating $\sin x \cos x$ by first letting $u=\sin x$ and then $u=\cos x$. Then show they are the "same"

Comment: Ahh... That makes a lot of sense. Thanks David and Voldemort.

Comment: If you were doing this in the context of a concrete application where you would need to explicitly solve for $c$ (e.g. an initial condition is given), your solution for $c$ in your second approach would be one less than the solution for the constant of integration that you should have in your first line. :)